# Script should be only run while leaving the page

Tags: jquery

I have a form which we can edit while clicking the edit button. While doing that i'm using the following script for showing the error message before leaving the page. It is showing the error message while clocking or leaving the page . But the problem is while saving the form it is submitting to some other page that time also it is showing the warning message. I want to remove the error message while submitting the form. The script is

```
function updateNew(value) {
     $(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
              return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
        });
}

<a href="#" onclick="updateNew({$ad_details[customer].id});"> Edit</a>
```

Comment: fyi - people really really hate that "do you REALLY want to leave"

Comment: <form name="frm1" action="submit.htm" onsubmit="unBindUnload()">

function unBindUnload() { 
    window.onbeforeunload = null
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a global variable like this

```
var Updated=false;
```

and after that in your function check for that variable value

```
function updateNew(value) {
     $(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
           if(Updated==false)
           {   
             return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
           } 
       });
}
```

first set value of `Updated` to `true` while submitting your form. this will do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps

```
  <a id="edit_but" href="#" onclick="updateNew({$ad_details[customer].id});"> Edit</a>


    $('#edit_but').click(function(){

    $(window).unbind('beforeunload');

    });
```